# Android 11 - Intent Image attachment not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider, android-11

Another new breaking changes for Android 11, attaching image is no longer working with Intent

FileProvider XML

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

AndroidManifest XML

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

This code will save image and triggers the intent, I retested it and it does save a file and return Uri starting with `content://`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
                //Create bitmap screen capture
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadBitmapFromView(refView));

                final String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/" + refView.getContext().getString(R.string.app_name);

                final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png");
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png"); //Cannot be */*
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, true);
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);

                final ContentResolver resolver = refView.getContext().getContentResolver();

                try {

                    Uri uriResolve = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

                    if (uriResolve == null || uriResolve.getPath() == null) {
                        throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");
                    }

                    try (OutputStream stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uriResolve)){

                        if (stream == null) {
                            throw new IOException("Failed to get output stream.");
                        }

                        if (!bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)) {
                            throw new IOException("Failed to save bitmap.");
                        }

                        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, false);
                        resolver.update(uriResolve, contentValues, null, null);

                shareToInstant("blablabla", uriResolve, refView.getContext())

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        //Don't leave an orphan entry in the MediaStore
                        resolver.delete(uriResolve, null, null);

                        e.printStackTrace();
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);


                    }
}



private static void shareToInstant(String content, Uri uri, View view) {

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content.replace(view.getContext().getString(R.string.show_more), "").replace(view.getContext().getString(R.string.show_less), "") + "\nFor more detail download app here : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + view.getContext().getPackageName());

        try {
            view.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share it Via"));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), R.string.unknown_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

You can ignore the FileProvider since I am using it for older version which is not included in the sample code.

I read some post like looping with `ResolveInfo` but I don't think that is the real solution, but rather a temporary hack. I wanted to know the culprit behind this and why, providing a source/documentation pointing to this changes is also a big help.

GMail's - Toast "Unable to attach file."

Twitter - Freezes (black screen)

Telegram - Working

Instagram - Not working

Skype - Not working

Viber - Only Image no text

Messenger - Only Image no text

Comment: You are not showing with wich uri you call shareToInstant(). And you do not need a FileProvider to begin with if you have the uri from .insert().

Comment: @Bitwise DEVS how did u solved this issue? i'm also facing the same issue

Comment: No solution so far?

Comment: @Agnohendrix not sure if this issue comes from GMail or the Android 11 itself, unfortunately I haven't check it again. I will try by this week and see if it exist on 12 and 13 as well.